# If user requests page that is unpublished, gets permission denied and page dies with too many redirections

Tags: nodes

When users without permission to administer nodes want to see content that is unpublished, they get a redirect loop.
I would rather show them a "this content is not anymore available."

Why is the redirection loop happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, i had settings for user to redirect to user/login after permission check, so teh system somehow ended in loop. I set special node page for such occassions, and now everything went normal again. Gisle thanks for comment (which easily could be answer to question)